# How to identify a track's genre in spotify api

Tags: response, spotify

I am looking for how to identify the song's (track) genre from spotify api.

Referring this particular documentation. "https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/get-track"
The sample response has the genre of a song. But the "Try it" option does not give me the expected response with "Genre"

Comment: The same question is already answered at the [Spotify Community](https://community.spotify.com/t5/Spotify-for-Developers/How-to-identify-a-track-s-genre-in-spotify-api/td-p/5602422)